# Firestore build error in abseil with Swift and Cocoapods

Tags: ios, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods, abseil

I have a swift project that is using Firestore.  There is a build issue when compiling the abseil pod that is included by Firestore.  When I attempt to build the project, I intermittently get this error:  `absl/base/internal/inline_variable.h file not found`.

I am using Xcode 11.4, Cocoapods 1.9.1, and Swift 5.

I have tried clearing derived data, updating pods, and deintegrating pods.  The one workaround that seems to work is the following, but when I switch devices for a build, the error occurs again.
1.  Comment out Firestore in the Podfile.
2.  Run `bundle exec pod install`
3.  Open Xcode and build.
4.  Uncomment Firestore in the Podfile.
5.  Run `bundle exec pod install`
6.  Open Xcode and build.

These steps will work temporarily.  Does anyone know of a way to get past this issue?

Here is the Podfile that I am using:

```
source 'git@git.myresearchapp.com:MyCompany/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'RNCryptor'
  pod 'KeychainSwift'
  pod 'Sentry', git: 'https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa.git', tag: '3.11.0'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'UICircularProgressRing', '~>4.1.0'
  pod 'IHKeyboardAvoiding', git: 'git@git.myresearchapp.com:MyCompany/IHKeyboardAvoiding.git', branch: 'master'
  pod 'GTProgressBar'
  pod 'AWSSNS'
  pod 'AWSCognito'
  pod 'AWSS3'
  pod 'Validator', git: 'https://github.com/jlowe234/validator'
  pod 'SwiftyOnboard', git: 'git@git.myresearchapp.com:MyCompany/SwiftyOnboard.git', branch: 'master'

  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by updating to the latest version of Sentry.  Apparently there is a build conflict between Firestore and version 3.11.0 of Sentry.
The fix is to change the Podfile entry for Sentry to the following:

```
pod 'Sentry'
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending hours searching and trying to solve this issue, the only solution was to add a pre-compiled Firestore SDK.

add this line to the PodFile

```
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '7.3.0'
```

refer to [firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks](https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks) for more info

Comment: Thanks! 
It may be compile error, so I  fix it this way.
and compiled firebase not include Storage,
so I add this to Podfile
```
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```